# How to deal with parameter names shadowing methods?

Tags: c++, gcc

The code below, compiled with gcc 4.9 with -std=c++14 -Wshadow produces the following warning:

```
main.cpp:12:24: warning: declaration of ‘id’ shadows a member of 'this' [-Wshadow]
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <string>

class Foo
{
public:
   Foo(std::string id);
   const std::string& id() const noexcept;
private:
   const std::string m_id;
};

Foo::Foo(std::string id) : m_id(id) {}
const std::string& Foo::id() const noexcept { return m_id; }

int main(int argc, char** argv) { return 0; }
```

The codebase I inherited contains **a lot** of such code. The naming convention the original authors chose (and I have to stick to) requires that getters are not prefixed with "get". Renaming parameters such as *id* just for the sake of getting rid of this warning sounds like a lot of work for nothing. At the moment I'm leaning towards adding a trailing underscore - it only has to be done in .cpp files so that ugliness won't reach public headers. Does anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: Don't use `-Wshadow`, i.e., use `-Wno-shadow`?

Comment: I used gcc 4.9.4 a lot during the last time. A lot of problems I remeber were caused by the "experimental" support of both, c++11 and c++14 (see https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/04/gcc-4.9.0). Do you encounter the same warning when using a newer compiler? Maybe try it with gcc 6.1 (see https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)

Comment: No warning from GCC 5.1 onwards

Comment: It's better to keep `id()` as it is, as it's a public method and part of the class's API. It is clear what it means when the client does `foo.id()`, whereas `foo.id_()` seem to me both ugly and may be confusing.

I agree with the above comments that either do not use `-Wno-shadow` or use a newer GCC.

Comment: This is going to be too opinion based tbh. But IMO trailing underscores are not only ugly but error prone because they look too much like the non-trailing counterparts. I eventually settled on `m_id` because it makes the "shadow" much more distinct than `id_` which is easier to confuse with `id`.  Also some people use the trailing underscore for function parameters and others use it for member names adding to the confusion and potential for mistakes.

Comment: The warning is simply a bug. As a parameter passed to a constructor did NOT hide anything at all as long you use it only for initializer list. It is quite valid to write: `class A{ int i; A(int i)i(i){}};`

Comment: What is the reason to use such outdated compilers? The last days it feels more than 20 times I see problems related using outdated compilers with modern c++. It was only partly implemented these days so why you hurt yourself?

Comment: How about starting using naming convention that prevents namespaces / types / mathods / variables from having the same names?